# Pass variable to modal which is the component

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-modal

I would like to pass data to modal, without pass all $scope. My modal is in component.

```
angular.module('app').component('testModal', {
  templateUrl: '/test-modal',
  bindings: {
    close: '&',
    dismiss: '&',
    resolve: '<'
  },


  controller: function ($scope, test) {
    var vm = this;
    this.test = test;

    this.save = () => {
      this.close()
    }

    this.cancel = function () {
      this.dismiss()
    }
  }
})
```

I try to pass data like below (from another controller)

```
function openModal() {
            testService.getTest().then(function(data) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    component: 'testModal',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        test: function () {
                          return data;
                        }
                      }
                  })   
            })

          }
```

But I have error: `angular.js:15567 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testProvider <- test <- catchError`

How can I deal with it? Why "test" isn't readed in my modal component?

Comment: So I see that you log in, are you ever going to respond to the answer I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a component with `$uibModal`, you don't have to inject the resolved data in the controller.  It will be accessible under `this.resolve` (if you use the `resolve` binding, as you did).

Change the component's controller definition to this:

```js
controller: function ($scope) {      // <-- removed `test` injection
    var vm = this;
    console.log(this.resolve.test);  // <-- `test` is on `resolve` object
                                     // <-- removed this.test = test
    this.save = () => {
      this.close()
    }
    this.cancel = function () {
      this.dismiss()
    }
}
```